# Laravel pass exact parameter to route

Tags: laravel, routes, localization

i have translated url which i need to redirect to the specific controller function, but i need also to pass an exact parameter.

For example i want to show all football news, but in the url i do not have the ID of the sport football (id=1) so i need to pass the parameter id=1 to the index() function.

```
Route::get('/football-news/', ['as' => 'news.index', 'uses' => 'NewsController@index']);
```

it is not an option to pass 'football' as a parameter, because it is just an example. The real route is translated and the code looks like that:

```
Route::get(LaravelLocalization::transRoute('routes.football.news'), ['as' => 'news.index', 'uses' => 'NewsController@index']);
```

Answer (score 2):

suppose you have a NewsController to fetch all news be like

```
class NewsController extends Controller
{
 public function index()
 {
  $news = News::all(); //you have to create News model
  return view('news.index', compact('news')); //use to pass data in view
 }

public function show($id)
 {
    $news_detail=News::find($id); //to fetch detail of news from database

    return view('news.show', compact('news_detail'));
 }
}
```

create index.php and show.php in views/news folder. in index.php

```
 @foreach($news as $news_item)
 <div>
  <a href="/news/{{$news_item->id}}">{{ $news_item->title }}</a>
 </div>
 @endforeach
```

here using "/news/{{$news_item->id}}" you can pass id of specific news into route file.
in show.php

```
<h1>news</h1>
<h1>
{{ $news_detail->title }}
</h1>
<ul class="list-group">
@foreach($news_detail->detail as $details)
   <li class="list-group-item">{{$details}}</li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```

in route file

```
Route::get('/news/{news}', 'NewsController@show');
```

now you have to create show($id) function in NewsController.php which parameter is id.

Answer (score 0):

You can append the index URL with `?id=1` parameter (eg. domain.com**?id=1**) and get it in your index controller action by using `Request::get('id');`

For example:

Url in template file:

```
<a href="domain.com?id=1" />
```

In your NewsController:

```
public function index(Request $request){
    $id = $request->get('id');
}
```

You should be able to have access to the parameter even though you didn't specify wildcards in the route file.

---

Edit:
you will have to call a different @action for a different route. You can pass in an id wildcard.
For example, in Route file:

```
Route::get('tennis-news/{id}', 'NewsController@tennisIndex');
Route::get('football-news/{id}', 'NewsController@footballIndex');
```

Then in the NewsControlleryou must have public methods `tennisIndex($id)` and `footballIindex($id)`, these methods will have access to the wildcard you set in the route.

For example, in NewsController

```
public function tennisIndex($id){
    $tennnis_news = News::where('sport'='tennis)->where('id', $id)->get();
    return view('tennis_news', compact('tennnis_news'));
}
```

Comment: But is is possible to tell the routes.php that in case of URL /football-news/ it should use NewsController@index(1), in case /tennis-news/ it should use index(2) and so on ?